# Iterating over a list of strings - How to replace a value before the index I use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I am self taught python learner, I am trying iterate over a list of words from a string I splitted, and using an index I try  to censor a given list of words( a and b). I am trying now to censor the word before and after the element from the given list of words to censor. I had succeed to censor the words after but I could not censor the word before the index. Here is the function I used:

```py
 def censor_four(email,a=proprietary_terms,b=negative_words):
    email=email.strip()
    email=email.split()
     # We'll append strings into this list for output.
    output = []

    # Keep track of where in the template string we are.
    index = 0

    # Add a while loop here.
    #for index in range(len(email)):
    for word in a or b:
        while index<len(email):
            if email[index]==word:
                if index>0:
                    email[index - 1]="0"*len(email[index - 1])
                email[index + 1]="/"*len(email[index + 1])
                output.append("*"*len(word))
                index+=1
            else:
                output.append(email[index])
                index+=1

    output=' '.join(output)
    return output
```

What is my mistake? Any hints?

Comment: Your code is somehow cryptic and problem description is ambiguous. Could you provide and example of input and output (desired and actual)? Also `for word in a or b:` probably doesn't do what you want - it iterates over list `a` if it's not empty, otherwise it iterates over list `b` - my guess is that you want to combine these lists (`a + b`).

Comment: I try to iterate over a string named (email) and censor two lists of strings a and  b . the output of this code is like:    " ....  but *** /// ...." I want to censor but as well that is why I used [index-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your intention properly. You want to censor words from one of two lists and also censor word before and after.

I'd change method of iterating.

```py
def censor_four(email, a=proprietary_terms, b=negative_words):
    email=email.strip()
    email=email.split()
    output = []
    censored = set(a+b)
    censor_next = False

    for word in email:
        if censor_next:
            output.append("/" * len(word))
            censor_next = False
        elif word in censored:
            if output:
                before_word = output.pop(-1)
                output.append("0" * len(before_word))
            output.append("*" * len(word))
            censor_next = True
        else:
            output.append(word)

    return " ".join(output)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted to do. Just another question: if output means if word in output, right?

Comment: `if output:` is a shorter version of `if len(output) > 0:`, so it checks if output list is not empty (otherwise popping value would raise exception).

Comment: I just fixed code (added `elif` instead of `if` in second condition).